# testing ruby code

Tags: ruby, testing

I wrote regular expression in Ruby. 
I created a folder name "test" and add 2 files in it.

*1st file:*

```
require 'test/unit'
class MyFirstTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_for_truth
  end
end
```

*2nd file:*

```
require 'my_math'
require 'test/unit'

class MyMathTest < Test::Unit::TestCcase
  def test_addition

  end

  def test_subtraction

  end
end
```

Now when i try to run this on ruby command line using  command `ruby my_math_test.rb`.

it says

> No such file or directory --ruby

I am using ruby 1.9.3

Do you know how to run this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I found the answer

Add a complete path.

example:

require 'test/unit' 
require 'c:/sites/cons/bets'

bets is the directory in which my .rb files are located.

Answer (score 0):

Test unit tests can be run by entering:

```
rake test
```

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rich, but i am not creating entire project here, i just have 2 files and i want to run a test on one of the file.

Comment: Take a look at this link then: http://flavio.castelli.name/2010/05/28/rails_execute_single_test/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where is your `my_math` script. But I guess it is not in your `$LOAD_PATH`.

Try the following:

```
require_relative 'my_math'
```

Comment: @Jags Glad to help. And I will be appreciate if you accept this answer by clicking the tick (check mark) on left under the vote arrows.